# How Do I Delete a DNS Domain Programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, wmi

I am building a C# web app to manage our DNS servers and am using the WMI Namespace for everything. The only thing I am having trouble with is deleting DNS Domains. Here is my code:

```
internal static bool DeleteDomainFromDns(string DnsServerName, string ContainerName, string Name)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNS_Domain WHERE DnsServerName = '" + DnsServerName + "' AND ContainerName = '" + ContainerName + "' AND Name = '" + Name + "'";
            ObjectQuery qry = new ObjectQuery(Query);
            DnsProvider dns = new DnsProvider();
            ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(dns.Session, qry);
            ManagementObjectCollection col = s.Get();
            dns.Dispose();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in col)
            {
                obj.Delete(); //Exception occurs here
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The error I get is: ManagementException was caught "Generic Failure". I've read online where people are deleting domains by using the zone namespace but that only works if the domain you want to delete is a zone itself. I need to delete domains that are not zones. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure you can dispose of that `DnsProvider` instance before iterating?

Comment: Yes, for two reasons. I don't use it past that point and because that's the way I do it for all my DNS delete methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way to delete a domain using WMI and also checked into a Powershell snapin called DNSShell but it doesn't look like there is a command to delete the domain.

Comment: @RJ: As much as I don't want to accept your answer, it looks like you have come the closest to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the script DnsResource.vbs from [Delete a Resource Record](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682130%28VS.85%29.aspx#_dns_delete_a_resource_record). It uses only DNS WMI Provider. So if it will work for your porpoise you can do the same in your C# program.

You can also consider to use [DnsModifyRecordsInSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682012%28VS.85%29.aspx). In Windos SDK (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\netds\dns\modifyrecords) you can find an example in C++ which use `DnsModifyRecordsInSet`. It demonstrate how to add a record in the DNS. If you use the second parameter `pDeleteRecords` instead of the first `pAddRecords` you will be able to delete any record in the DNS.

Comment: Thanks for trying but I don't have any problems deleting resource records. I am having a problem deleting domains.

Comment: @mcass20: the resource type can be any from the `DNS_RECORD` struct (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682082(VS.85).aspx) inclusive 'A' record, 'NS' record and 'CNAME' record or sometimes 'MX' record and 'SOA' recored which are mostly used to define a subdomain (see http://manual.intl.indoglobal.com/ch03s05.html). Just look as DNS Server how the subdomain is defined in your environment and delete the corresponding records.

Comment: Thanks again for your insight, however, deleting the records in the domain doesn't delete the domain container itself which is my goal here.